# How to handle frontend stack in Symfony 3.3

Tags: php, symfony, webpack, vuejs2, frontend

according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html I want to write my frontend with modern technologies. I decided to make components in Vue2.
But my all development experience is only in backend so how can I handle components on some pages?

For example, I want to have other components on register page and another stack on listing. In docs I saw that output js is only single file so how to detect page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, latest version of Symfony suggests to use Webpack [Encore Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@symfony/webpack-encore) which generates build configuration for [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) (which is a modern JS bundler).

> For example, I want to have other components on register page and another stack on listing. In docs I saw that output js is only single file so how to detect page?

The docs have the relevant example: [Creating Page-Specific CSS/JS](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/page-specific-assets.html). Example from there:

```
// webpack.config.js
Encore
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/main.js')
    .addStyleEntry('global', './assets/css/global.scss')
    .addEntry('checkout', './assets/js/checkout.js')
;
```

Encore Component provides a nice high-level API, however I highly recommended to learn the Webpack [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) for a better understanding of its capabilities.